# Example of Logical Schema vs Physical Schema?

Tags: schema

I've read through multiple Q&As attempting to intuitively understand the difference between logical schemas and physical schemas.

Unfortunately, I've only been able to take away the following vague definitions.

- **Logical** refers to a high-level definition of data including tables, data types, etc.
- **Physical** refers to the 'implementation', i.e. how data is actually stored.

Is this correct? And if so, is there a concrete example or two that can drive home these definitions?

**edit**: I know that this question has probably been asked many times over, but I'm specifically asking for an illuminating example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22069941/5059085) probably defines the difference between the two pretty well.

Specifically these two points:

> A logical schema is a conceptual model of the data. In relational databases, it's often platform-agnostic - i.e. the logical schema can, in principle, be implemented on any SQL database.

> The physical schema converts the logical schema into an implementation that works on a particular database platform. Sometimes, this is a largely mechanical exercise, applying the right datatypes to the attributes...

So in other words, if you had a schema that represented `MovieTheaters`, you'd probably have a few tables `Movies`, `TicketSales`, `ConcessionSnacks`. The `TicketSales` table would probably have a `TicketId` column, a `Price` column, and a `MovieId` column. This high level detail is essentially your logical schema.

Once you start implementing this schema on a specific database system, take Microsoft SQL Server for example, and using features and data types specific to Microsoft SQL Server, is when it becomes a physics schema. For example, your `TicketSales` table's `TicketId` column could be a `INT` data type with a **primary key** on it, and the `MovieId` could be a `BIGINT` field with a many-to-one **foreign key** on it, and the `Price` column could be a `DECIMAL(4,2)`. And the `Movies` table can have a *unique constraint* on the `MovieTitle` column to prevent duplicate Movies being inserted into it.

Comment: Gotcha, so to clarify - a 'schema' that we see in a statement such as `CREATE SCHEMA` may include both logical & physical schema information. The logical schema info might be table names, field names, etc. And the physical schema info will be indexes, constraints, data types, etc.

Comment: @NoahStebbins Yea I think that's a fair statement. The **physical schema** contains the **logical schema** in a sense because it is a concrete implementation of it. (The **logical schema** is an abstraction of the **physical schema**.) Though the `CREATE SCHEMA` statement in most SQL languages really just means create a new schema name. Schema names are usually a prefix to the objects (tables, views, etc) that belong under it (as a way to group related objects of the same schema). More so, you'll see the **logical** and **physical** schema in the `CREATE TABLE` statements, for example.